# Apple Mach-O Linker Error using Core Data classes in OCUnit

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, ocunit

OK, here's my code in my test class:

```
 - (NSManagedObjectContext*)managedObjectContextWithConcurrencyType:(NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType)concurrencyType {
    NSManagedObjectModel *mom = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];
    STAssertNotNil(mom, @"Can not create MOM from main bundle");

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:mom];
    STAssertNotNil(psc, @"Can not create persistent store coordinator");
    NSPersistentStore *store = [psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSInMemoryStoreType configuration:nil URL:nil options:nil error:0];
    STAssertNotNil(store, @"Can not create In-Memory persistent store");

    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:concurrencyType];
    moc.persistentStoreCoordinator = psc;

    return moc;
}
```

And here's the failure message when trying to use the method in a test method:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_NSInMemoryStoreType", referenced from:
      -[CrosswordItemTests managedObjectContextWithConcurrencyType:] in CrosswordItemTests.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSEntityDescription", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in CrosswordItemTests.o
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSManagedObjectContext", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in CrosswordItemTests.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSManagedObjectModel", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in CrosswordItemTests.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSPersistentStoreCoordinator", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in CrosswordItemTests.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I thought I imported the needed classes like that in the .h file:

```
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In my experience i386 errors tend to come from missing libraries. Its not enough to just #import them in your file, you must also add them to the project libraries. Go into the Project Target -> Build Phases -> Link Binary with Libraries and in your case add the libraries associated  with Core Data.

Comment: Aaaaaaaaah, I didn't know that I have to link CoreData twice – first to the normal build target AND second to the test build target. That solves my issues, thanks to both!

Answer (score 8):

You probably haven't linked the library to the target.

[image]

Taken from: http://yannickloriot.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/Link-CoreData-Framework-To-The-Project.png

Answer (score 0):

Changing 'No Common Blocks' from Yes to No (under Targets->Build Settings->Apple LLVM - Code Generation) fixed the problem.
This fixed my problem. Hope it will help to you.