# Apple Mach-O Linker Error: Using Xcode 4.6 compile VLC for IOS on Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, vlc

HI~ I followed the page: forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=108069, and compile VLC successfully.
However, when I wanted to run the project on simulator by Xcode, the errors(Apple Mach-O Linker Error) happened.

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>
> "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MLFile", referenced from:
>
> ```
>  objc-class-ref in MVLCMovieListViewController.o
>
>  l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_MLFile_$_HD in MLFile+HD.o
> ```
>
> "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MLMediaLibrary", referenced from:
>
> ```
>  objc-class-ref in MVLCMovieListViewController.o
>
>  objc-class-ref in MobileVLCAppDelegate.o
> ```
>
> "_OBJC_CLASS_$_VLCMedia", referenced from:
>
> ```
>  objc-class-ref in MVLCMovieViewController.o
> ```
>
> "_OBJC_CLASS_$_VLCMediaPlayer", referenced from:
>
> ```
>  objc-class-ref in MVLCMovieViewController.o
> ```
>
> "_OBJC_CLASS_$_VLCTime", referenced from:
>
> ```
>  objc-class-ref in MVLCMovieGridViewCell.o
>
>  objc-class-ref in MVLCMovieTableViewCell.o
> ```
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386

How can I fix it? Thanks!

---

To Morkrom,
Thanks for your reply, I did this, but it seems not work.

http://ppt.cc/OlKD,
http://ppt.cc/Khb5

Comment: I've added a link to another solution to a similar problem.

Comment: See also.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312915/apple-mach-o-linker-error-using-core-data-classes-in-ocunit/17275174#17275174

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add those obc-class-refs to your compile sources. In the lefthand column in XCode, click on your blue project icon -> click on your app's name under "Targets" -> click on "Build Phases" -> click on "Compile Sources" -> click "+" button at bottom of "Compile Sources", and add each of the obc-class-ref symbols referenced in your output.

---

You also want to ensure that these files have your project set as the target:
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14147640/what-is-my-target-and-how-do-i-add-a-file-to-it-for-unit-testing/14148008#14148008).